# How to get uniform stroke in Illustrator using brush tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush

I am using **Adobe Illustrator** and a **Wacom tablet**. When curved lines are drawn using **brush tool**, I am getting non uniform stroke widths as in the attached image. Is there any way to achieve uniform brush stroke using a caligraphic round brush in Illustrator ?

[image: What I get when I draw curves now.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/333657-illustrator-feature-requests/suggestions/34128700-calligraphic-brush-blob-brush-appearance-anomalie).  Adobe says it's fixed, but users disagree as you can see from the comments.

My own workaround is not to use such a small brush. Draw the artwork at a larger scale, with a larger brush, on a larger artboard. Alternatively you could scale the artwork up. Seems to fix it too.

Here's a calligraphic brush stroke applied to a path (top), scaling it up fixes the problem (bottom)

[image]